# Interpolate five year data annually

Tags: python, r, interpolation

I have a large csv file recorded at five year interval from 1945- 2010 for each country as shown below.

```
> head(data)
   year name     value
1: 1945  USA 110265118
2: 1950  USA 122994019
3: 1955  USA 134001770
4: 1960  USA 150234347
5: 1965  USA 167515758
6: 1970  USA 172867051
```

```
> tail(data)
   year name  value
1: 1985  WSM 152325
2: 1990  WSM 159500
3: 1995  WSM 161677
4: 2000  WSM 174600
5: 2005  WSM 177510
6: 2010  WSM 180140
```

I would like to upsample my data annualy and interpolate the value column.
I have tried the below line of code but can't figure out why am getting an error.

```
dat <- data[data[, .(year = seq.int(year[1], year[.N], 1.0)), by=name], on=c('year', 'name')][,value := zoo::na.approx(value, na.rm = FALSE)]
Error: Column 1 of result for group 61 is type 'integer' but expecting type 'double'. Column types must be consistent for each group.
```

Thoughts on how to achieve my desired results are highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for a data.table solution specifically?

Comment: DEVELOPER_ONE please upvote and accept my answer if it does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Base R but should work with data.tables too, Note this won't work if your first value is NA after merging with your data at the lower level of granularity (i.e. years < 1945), if that is the case let me know and I will re-work my solution:

```
data.frame(do.call("rbind", lapply(split(df, df$name), function(x){

      # Find the range: date_range => Date vector
      date_range <- range(as.numeric(df$year))

      # Generate a sequence, having every date in the range:
      # date_lkp => data.frame
      date_lkp <- data.frame(year = seq(date_range[1], date_range[2]))

      # Merge with date_range: df2 => data.frame
      df2 <- merge(date_lkp, df, all.x = TRUE)

      # Use linear interpolation to populate missing values:
      # value => integer vector
      df2$value[which(is.na(df2$value))] <- approx(df2$value,
                                                   n = nrow(df2))$y[which(is.na(df2$value))]

      # Fill down the missing names: name => character vector
      df2$name <- na.omit(df2$name)[cumsum(!(is.na(df2$name)))]

      # Define return object: df2 => .GlobalEnv() 
      return(df2)
      }
    )
  ),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE, row.names = NULL)
```

Data:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread(
  "year name     value
1945  USA 110265118
1950  USA 122994019
1955  USA 134001770
1960  USA 150234347
1965  USA 167515758
1970  USA 172867051
1985  WSM 152325
1990  WSM 159500
1995  WSM 161677
2000  WSM 174600
2005  WSM 177510
2010  WSM 180140")
df <- data.frame(dt)
```

Python using Pandas:

```
# Initialise pandas in session: 
import pandas as pd

# year => list of integers: 
year = [1945, 1950, 1955, 1960, 1965, 1970, 1985, 1990, 1995, 2000, 2005, 2010]

# name => list of strings: 
name = ["USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "WSM","WSM","WSM","WSM","WSM","WSM"]

# value => list of integers: 
value = [110265118,  122994019, 134001770, 150234347,167515758, 172867051, 152325, 159500, 161677, 174600,177510,
         180140]

# Create Data Frame from dict of lists above: df => Data Frame
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': year, 'name': name, 'value': value})

# Function upsampling and interpolating data: upsample_df => function 
def upsample_df(g_df):
    years = pd.DataFrame({'year': [*range(int(g_df.year.min()), int(g_df.year.max()+1), 1)]})
    m_df = pd.merge(years, g_df, how = 'left', on = [*set(years.columns) & set(g_df.columns)])
    df2 = m_df.interpolate(method = 'linear')
    df2['name'] = df2['name'].ffill()
    return(df2)

# Apply function groupwise (according to name): upsampled_df => Data Frame
upsampled_df = df.groupby('name').apply(upsample_df)

# Reset the index of upsampled_df: upsampled_df.index => integer
upsampled_df.index = [*range(1, len(upsampled_df)+1)]

# Output result to console: upsampled_df => stdout (console)
print(upsampled_df.head())
```

Comment: You are forgetting that this should be made country by country.

Comment: @RuiBarradas yes that's true. One moment I will edit sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a simple solution in python with resampling and filtering, please see code below.

input dataframe:

```
   A        B     C
  1945     USA    5
  1950     USA   10
  1955     USA   15
  1945   Brazil   6
  1950   Brazil   8
  1955   Brazil  10
  1945  Germany   7
  1950  Germany   8
  1955  Germany   9
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C'])
df['A'] =[1945,1950,1955,1945,1950,1955,1945,1950,1955]
df['B'] =['USA','USA','USA','Brazil','Brazil','Brazil','Germany','Germany','Germany']
df['C'] =[5,10,15,6,8,10,7,8,9]


df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'], format='%Y')
df.set_index(df['A'],inplace=True)
df.drop(columns=['A'],inplace=True)
print(df)

list_of_countries = df['B'].tolist()
list_of_unique_countries = list(set(list_of_countries))
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for country in list_of_unique_countries:
    copy_of_df = df.copy()
    filtered_df = copy_of_df[copy_of_df['B']==country]
    filtered_df = filtered_df.resample('Y',closed='left').max()
    filtered_df['C'] = filtered_df['C'].interpolate(method='linear')
    filtered_df['B'] = country
    new_df = new_df.append(filtered_df)

new_df.index = new_df.index.strftime('%Y')

print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
A     B     C

1945  Germany   7.0
1946  Germany   7.2
1947  Germany   7.4
1948  Germany   7.6
1949  Germany   7.8
1950  Germany   8.0
1951  Germany   8.2
1952  Germany   8.4
1953  Germany   8.6
1954  Germany   8.8
1955  Germany   9.0
1945      USA   5.0
1946      USA   6.0
1947      USA   7.0
1948      USA   8.0
1949      USA   9.0
1950      USA  10.0
1951      USA  11.0
1952      USA  12.0
1953      USA  13.0
1954      USA  14.0
1955      USA  15.0
1945   Brazil   6.0
1946   Brazil   6.4
1947   Brazil   6.8
1948   Brazil   7.2
1949   Brazil   7.6
1950   Brazil   8.0
1951   Brazil   8.4
1952   Brazil   8.8
1953   Brazil   9.2
1954   Brazil   9.6
1955   Brazil  10.0
```

Hope this helps you with a similar solution in R.